# SPSS different t values but same p?

Tags: spss

I have previously used SPSS to run my statistics.  I no longer have access to SPSS but wanted to compare my previous results to another statistical package.  I have run my analysis several times in different software programs and I get the same significance values but I different t values.  Is this possible?  Has anyone experienced this???

Comment: "I have run my analysis several times in different software programs and I get the same significance values but I different t values."  Can you elaborate with examples?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to be sure what's going on. What exactly was done in SPSS? What are you doing in something else?

Answer (score 0):

The same significance values you are getting should be a coincidence, because the p-value is tied to the percentile location of the t value in its associated distribution.

You might want to check your degrees of freedom and standard errors and see if they are also the same, if you have the records available. They should be the same if you are just replicating the results with the same data.